# Redirection loop

Tags: php, html

**PROBLEM**

I don't really understand as to why I'm getting a redirect loop. But I can pinpoint where it's happening but I can't explain why. It's the `self::redirect("?" . self::$queryString)` line that is giving me problem. If I remove it I can navigate just fine but when I put it back it gives me the error again. (Don't know if that's the problematic line but I think it is since when I delete that line it no longer does the redirect loop.)

```
if (self::curPage() == "/clan.php" && isset($_GET['clan'])) {
  self::$queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
} elseif (self::curPage() == "/clan/profile.php") {
  self::redirect("?" . self::$queryString);
}
```

**WHAT I WANT**

What I want is basically is to add the previous `$queryString` (The GET variables). And whenever the user navigates from the <kbd>/clan.php</kbd> page they will be transferred over to the new url and then the previous `$queryString` will be concatenated at the end of the url.

If you have a way of solving this through improvements, new method, or any other way I would really appreciate it. Further questions can be asked down at the comments and I will try and answer them as fast and best as I can.

**WHAT I'VE THOUGHT OF**

- Changing the  `a (link tag)` and changing the href value to the current/previous GET variable/parameter. Don't kow how to do it though except perhaps something like this. That's the only part I've thought of so far.

  ```
  var currentGET = <?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>;
  if (window.location.href == '/clan.php') {
     $('a').attr('href', window.location.href + "?" + currentGET);
  }
  ```

**EXTRA**

> This is the `curPage()` function!

```
public static function curPage(){
    $parts = parse_url(self::curPageURL());
    return $parts["path"];
}
```

Comment: Can you add the error?

Comment: `/clan.php` and `/clan/profile.php` imply two separate HTTP requests, but you don't appear to have any persistence of the previous query string before redirecting. Are you using the session anywhere?  Does `self::curPage()` return the script URI or the URI _and_ query string?

Comment: @didando8a Chrome only gives me that error. `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I'm going to update the question right now to show you what the code is for that `curPage()` function.

Comment: Do you have some abstraction for reading/writing `$_SESSION`? In order to make use of `$queryString` stored on the `clan.php` request, you would have to store it in the user's session and retrieve it on the `/clan/profile.php` request to reuse it.

Comment: You should clarify the "WHAT I WANT" section by adding the sequence of HTTP requests you expect to make.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I'm a beginner programmer so I don't know what you're mostly trying to say. But I don't have any abstraction for reading/writing $_SESSION's.

Comment: @rojoca Hmmmmm what do you mean? Can you give me an example of 'sequence of HTTP requests you expect to make'?

Comment: You're getting a redirect loop because after the redirect, the same condition is being met again so it redirects again, and so on. You need to add to the second `elseif` a condition that excludes the redirected page such as the URL not containing the query string added to the redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two lines below are definitely causing the redirect loop:

```
} elseif (self::curPage() == "/clan/profile.php") {
    self::redirect("?" . self::$queryString);
```

The reason it is doing this is because you are checking if the current URI is `/clan/profile.php` and if it is you redirect it to itself with a query string and then run the check again even though the query string is present.

It would need to be something like this to prevent an infinite redirect:

```
} elseif (self::curPage() == "/clan/profile.php" && false == **QUERY STRING CONDITION**) {
    self::redirect("?" . self::$queryString);
```

`**QUERY STRING CONDITION**` needs to be replaced by some sort of check of the query string that indicates the URI is correct and you don't want to redirect them.